# Is it possible to add photo-realistic clouds in ArcGlobe animations?

Tags: 3d, visualisation, animation, arcglobe

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15329/which-software-to-use-to-create-professional-fly-over-fly-through-animations) asked about the best software to produce professional fly-through animations, and included a link to a nice [video of the Grand Canyon](http://www.nps.gov/grca/photosmultimedia/fly-through.htm).

That video includes photo-realistic clouds in the sky. Is it possible to add clouds like this in ArcGlobe?

Comment: [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PvNinwDnls) is another fly-over featuring clouds. The water reflection is a nice touch too.

Comment: @Jakub very nice. I once saw a 3D demo which had moving water, trees swaying randomly in the wind, etc. Definitely not ArcGlobe though!

Comment: You may have to look at another program entirely. To my mind, Arc is more about the analysis than all the finer points of presentation. Even when making paper maps, we've had to edit its output to make it fit for publication. That said, I haven't used their software in a while.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to replace the "starry sky" skydome texture (assuming that's what it is) with a "cloudy sky" one? The atmospheric halo can be disabled or reduced through the Globe Properties option, but there is no option for replacing the skydome texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clouds on the animation seem to be on an vertical plane at a given distance (when the "plane is turning, there is some sort of acceleration of the closest clouds, but far and close clouds don't seem to be moving with respect to each other when the "plane" is approaching.) So, instead of trying to change the background (which doesn't seem to be possible), I propose the following workaround :

build a very tall textured 3D object with a 2D sky image for the texture. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q80000000m000000 as you probably know. If it is far enough from the position of your plane, and you don't look too high above the horizon, you can have the same result as in the nice movie you've shown.